# Flutter app rejected in google play due to Violation of Misleading Claims policy

Tags: flutter, dart, google-play, google-play-console

My app rejected due to Violation of Misleading Claims policy..
this is the mail I received:

App Status: Rejected
Your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to the policy issue(s) listed below. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.

Issue found: Violation of Misleading Claims policy
Your app contains content that doesn't comply with the Misleading Claims policy.
Apps must provide an accurate disclosure, description and images/video of their functionality in all parts of the metadata.
Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

App screenshot (en-US): Please see attached screenshot APP_SCREENSHOT-7133.png
Version code 5: In-app experience: Please see attached screenshot IN_APP_EXPERIENCE-4808.png
About the Misleading Claims policy
We don’t allow apps that contain false or misleading information or claims, including in the description, title, icon, and screenshots, such as apps that are improperly categorized, including but not limited to, the app rating or app category.

and here the screenshots:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgUrn.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbvYe.png)

can anyone solve me this problem?

Comment: I don't know where is the problem exactly, in app listing or in appbundel... @Dhafin Rayhan

Comment: okay, I will fix that but what about second screen with red marks? @Dhafin Rayhan

Comment: Oops sorry my translation was wrong, but I guess it has something to do with claims... so make sure no advertising text that has an irresponsible claim. Btw you should contact Google for this instead of asking here, I'm sure that's the intended way

Comment: Since it mentions "App screenshot (en-US)" maybe the error is that you have arabic screenshots where you should have English ones?